# freepascal/delphi components not appearing (z-order issue I think)

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, z-order

I had a PANEL on the form. Then dynamically I create many more panels and place them on the form to look like a menu.

By mistake I deleted the main PANEL. then put it back as a new control.

Now the dynamic buttons don't show. But there's no error. So I'm guessing that the dynamic components are there but invisible (behind the main PANEL).

Is there a way to fix this? I can't seem to find a z-order property for the components.

Please help.

Here's the code segment:

```
  For MenuItemCount:= 1 to MenuItemLimit Do
      Begin
      MenuButtons[MenuItemCount] := TPanel.Create(Self);
      With MenuButtons[MenuItemCount] do
          begin

            Width:=180 - (10*MenuItem[MenuItemCount].Level);
            Left:=4+10*MenuItem[MenuItemCount].Level;

            Height:=25;
            Top:= 5 + Height * (MenuItemCount-1);
            Color:= clMenu;
            Cursor:=crHandPoint;

            Parent := MenuGroup; //Parent container for the items.

            Caption := MenuItem[MenuItemCount].Title;

      end;//End for
```

`MenuGroup` is the parent panel that is placed at design-time.

Comment: What do you mean with *main PANEL*, is that your `MenuGroup` container ? If so, then the child controls were destroyed. Btw. it wouldn't be enough to just add a parent control and hope that children will take it as their parent, you would have to assign them to that parent again. But still, when you destroy a parent, you'll destroy all of its children.

Comment: @TLama by main PANEL I meant MenuGroup. It's the Panel that holds the dynamically created ones. This WORKED. Then after I had accidentally deleted the MenuGroup panel and put it back, the dynamic panels don't show on it.

Comment: Then they were destroyed since except `Owner` passed in constructor also `Parent` is responsible for destroying all of its children when it's destroyed.

Comment: @TLama Excuse me for my ignorance... I don't quite get what you're saying. If you noticed the code, I AM setting the parent property for each dynamic component. If this is wrong, would you please show me how I should change it? Thanks!

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine (otherwise you wouldn't even see those controls), but if you destroy that parent, those controls are destroyed as well.

Comment: @TLama But I ain't destroying anything... It's all jsut there. The only time they get destroyed is when I close the form. I'm puzzled

Comment: @TLama. MenuGroup is a panel placed in design time. The other panels are created runtime on top of it but they don't show. Nothing is destroyed, the only thing that happened (apparently) was the removal and replacing of the design time container panel.

Comment: @GolezTrol I just noticed something... I took off the panel and tried putting the dynamically created panels on the FORM. Even that doesn't show! I even tried echoing the CAPTIONS of each component created and they SHOW on a message box. But I'm not getting any component on the screen :(

Comment: What happens if you move this code to a new test project. If you can't reproduce it in a test project, there may be other code in your project that triggers this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the method `SendToBack`, which lets you send a control to the back (and its `BringToFront` counterpart).

But I think it won't solve your problem. The 'Z-order' of components by default is the order in which they are created. The design time panel is created before the dynamic panels, even once you have removed it and put a new one on the form.

What I think happened (though it's a hard guess without seeing your code), is that you tried to find the panel by name, like this:

```
var
  ParentPanel: TPanel;
  DynamicPanel: TPanel;
begin
  ParentPanel := FindComponent('PanelX') as TPanel;

  DynamicPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  DynamicPanel.Parent := ParentPanel;
```

This would work, but if you remove PanelX, and put in a new panel with a slightly different name, FindComponent won't find the panel and return nil. The DynamicPanels will have nil as a parent, causing them not to show up.

Comment: A slight issue: The end says `end //for`, but it's actually the end of the `with` block. That means that following code will be executed in the for loop as well.

Comment: Apart from that, the code looks fine. All you can do is check if it is actually executed (set a breakpoint), check if MenuItem[MenuItemCount].Level isn't some rediculous value (either negative or >= 18) and if MenuGroup isn't accidentally nil. You might try to set the parent before you set top, height, etc, but I don't that that should make a difference.

Comment: Forgot to mention: If MenuGroup is the parent of those dynamic controls, they cannot appear behind MenuGroup in the Z-order. Controls are always on top of their parent and only have a relative Z-ordering inside their parent.

Comment: Thanks again... That's exactly what I did. I printed every element as it ran through the loop. I think it's a bug. And like you said, I moved the Parent setting to the line soon after create, and yes, you are right, it makes no difference :(

Comment: In that case I'm sorry. I cannot point to other obvious problems in this code without resorting to random guessing.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for you help. Your time spent is much appreciated. In addition to setting the parent like you've mentioned, I did a few things - Reset debugger, closed Lazarus and came back, Set the Left property to a fixed value, and finally changed it to the variables I needed. Strangely, it works now. Perhaps I had changed something down the line after I lost the big panel. Thanks a million!